# Как с помощью спецификаций реализовать исключения по 3 связанным таблицам?

Tags: java, hibernate-criteria

Есть три таблицы. Эмейлы, рассылки и типы рассылок. **Эмейлы** один ко многим к **рассылкам**. **Типы рассылок** многие ко одному к **рассылкам**. Нужно через спецификации исключить все эмейлы которые содержат в рассылках хоть один определённый тип рассылок за определенный период. В метод мне приходит просто id типа рассылки и Period. Этот вариант работает если у эмейла только одна рассылка.

```
private static Specification<Email> isModelExcludeEquals(List<Long> modelId, Period period) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            query.distinct(true);
             return  criteriaBuilder.and(
              criteriaBuilder.lessThan(root.join("mailing",JoinType.LEFT).get("date"), LocalDateTime.now().minus(period)),
              root.join("mailing", JoinType.LEFT).get("model").get("id").in(modelId)));};
    }
```

Comment: Если честно, то я не очень понял вопрос.

То есть есть 3 таблицы, как они связаны между собой?
А если приходит id типа рассылки, то зачем он нужен, если ты будешь отбирать все рассылки без типа рассылки?

Comment: @ДмитрийАлексеенко По каждому эмейлу может происходить рассылка и они бывают разных типов. То есть эмейл содержит в себе коллекцию рассылок. Рассылки бывают разных типов и у них есть поле типа рассылки. id нужен что бы смотреть есть ли у эмейла эта рассылка, и если есть то в выборку итоговую эмейл не включать

Comment: То есть мы получаем все рассылки за исключение рассылки с id который пришел.

А Period это конкретная дата?

Comment: Какой формируется запрос в данный момент? Как он выглядит вообще

Comment: @ДмитрийАлексеенко мы должны получить эмейлы, у которых никогда не встречалась данная рассылка за время от (сейчас - period) до сейчас. Sql запрос https://codeshare.io/9O39X7

Comment: А зачем 3 left join к одной и той же тбл?

Comment: @ДмитрийАлексеенко потому что 3 таблицы, я из корневого элемента добираюсь к остальным таблицам, корневой элемент эмейл

Comment: И что? если делать 3 join`а к одной и тоже тбл, то от этого не затрагивает другие таблицы - это затрагивает каждый раз одну таблицу. И выгоднее использовать inner join / join т.к. он сразу откинет все лишнее.

Вот как я вижу этот запрос корректным https://codeshare.io/9O39X7 надеюсь мои изменения увидишь.

Comment: @ДмитрийАлексеенко запрос генерит гибернейт, мне нужно исходить из реализации спецификации

Comment: criteriaBuilder это какой то кастомный класс?

Comment: @ДмитрийАлексеенко не, этот класс идет вместе со спецификациями

Comment: Как-то не складывается ты прислал ссылку на формировавшийся запрос, там охренеть как много условий, но в коде эти условия никак не обыгрваются, а что в переменнй `query` хранится?